# which inotify event signals the completion of a large file operation?

Tags: python, inotify, pyinotify

for large files or slow connections, copying files may take some time.

using pyinotify, i have been watching for the IN_CREATE event code. but this seems to occur at the *start* of a file transfer. i need to know when a file is completely copied - it aint much use if it's only half there.

when a file transfer is *finished and completed*, what inotify event is fired?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`IN_CLOSE` *probably* means the write is complete.  This isn't for sure since some applications are bad actors and open and close files constantly while working with them, but if you know the app you're dealing with (file transfer, etc.) and understand its' behaviour, you're probably fine.  (Note, this doesn't mean the transfer completed successfully, obviously, it just means that the process that opened the file handle closed it).

`IN_CLOSE` catches both `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` and `IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE`, so make your own decisions about whether you want to just catch one of those.  (You probably want them both - `WRITE/NOWRITE` have to do with file permissions and not whether any writes were actually made).

There is more documentation (although annoyingly, not *this* piece of information) in [Documentation/filesystems/inotify.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/inotify.txt).

Comment: my question pertains specifically to file copying in nautilus. in this case, IN_CLOSE_WRITE is sufficient.
IN_CLOSE by itself does not exist in pyinotify.

Answer (score 2):

For my case I wanted to execute a script after a file was fully uploaded. I was using WinSCP which writes large files with a `.filepart` extension till done.

I first started modifying my script to ignore files if they're themselves ending with .filepart or if there's another file existing in the same directory with the same name but  .filepart extension, hence that means the upload is not fully completed yet.

But then I noticed at the end of the upload, when all the parts have been finished, I have a `IN_MOVED_IN` notification getting triggered which helped me run my script exactly when I wanted it.

If you want to know how your file uploader behaves, add this to the incrontab:

```
/your/directory/ IN_ALL_EVENTS echo "$$ $@ $# $% $&"
```

and then

```
tail -F /var/log/cron
```

and monitor all the events getting triggered to find out which one suits you best.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a dummy file at the end of the transfer? You can use the IN_CLOSE or IN_CREATE event code on the dummy. The important thing is that the dummy as to be transfered as the last file in the sequence.

I hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

The event IN_ATTRIB which is triggered at the end of the transfer works fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).